# How to read a text file in Flex stored on a webserver

Tags: apache-flex, web-applications, actionscript, remote-access

I have a text file stored on a webserver (Tomcat). This file get updated daily by a different program.

Now, I want my flex application to read from that file and show the data in one of the compnenets for example DataGrid , Text box. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two options:

1) Flex app resides in tomcat container (or another Java EE container).

So you could use an blaze ds scheme and access to text file with Java app, and Flex invoque the Java app through Remote Object methodology

2) Flex app is external to tomcat container

The solution that I could use is develope a single Java webservice that returns the content of the text file.

So the Flex app invoque webservice and return the content with HttpService methodology

Comment: I have sth like this working on my projects.
I use webservices to access some info from my tomcat server.